# Django how to use login_required with TokenAuthentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

Hi I am trying to use [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) from Django rest-framework.

I am able to use this with my views with rest api.

```
#view_rest.py
class CartList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    filter_class = CartFilter
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user_id'] = request.user.id
        return generics.ListCreateAPIView.create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user.id
        return Cart.objects.filter(user_id_id=user)
```

But In my custom views it is not authenticating,

```
#custom_django_views.py
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def order(request):
    '''Returns page to place order
    '''
    return render(request,"order.html",{})

#this will redirect me to login page.



#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'myapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'site_aggrigator.middleware.SubdomainMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
#rest framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

I am not able to understand why request for custom_django_views, is not authenticated? When does authentication happens?

Comment: try using @permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,)) above your custom function based view.

Comment: I am not able to find `permission_classes`. I have tried with `permission_required(permissions.IsAuthenticated)`. This is not working.

Comment: from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes

Comment: @Zealous, still no success.

Comment: your custom view is not api view , right?

Comment: custom view is same as https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77080/discussion-between-netro-and-zealous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case is wrong. Django rest framework doesn't allow these things.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#javascript-clients

Session authentication should be used for web browser. And they are not required when using it for mobile.

Rest framswork views take care of csrf validation when using token authentication.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
@api_view(["GET"])
def your_function(request):
    pass
```